# Python repeating a function using the result of the previous function

Tags: python, function

I am a bit new to python and have been searching and trying different solutions to this issue.

I need to create a function that not only counts down within the function but also adds the previous results.

To help put this in context:

I have a formula for a weekly cost where Time corresponds to the current time within the model. It looks like the following:

```
week1 = 5000**((Time-1))
week2 = 5000**((Time-2))
...
```

(where the number next to time is increasing by one over a specific range)

Now the end result needs to be (for example)

```
if Time > 5:
        return week1+ week2+ week3+ week4+ week5
 elif Time == 5:
        return week1+ week2+ week3+ week4
```

This would continue to time <=1. So I need a formula where not only is the function repeated a specific number of times adding the previous result, but one of the variables in the formula also changes based on the count. I know there must be an efficient way to do this with a loop but I can not seem to figure it out.

Any help would be amazing!
Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to compute 5000^0 + 5000^1 + 5000^2 + ... + 5000^(Time-1)? It's a geometric progression, and is equal to (5000^Time - 1) / 4999.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your formula is wrong, it should be:

```
week1 = 5000 * (Time-1)
```

With simple loop:

```
result = 0
for i in range(Time):
    result += 5000 * (Time - i)
print result
```

You can achieve it in one line using both `sum` and `generator expression`.

```
result = sum(5000 *(Time - i) for i in range(Time))
```

Comment: There's no list comprehension there. Also, `Time` should be counting down (to what endpoint I don't know), not up.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this problem is using recursion. Put simply, it is a function that will continue to call itself until a specific condition is met (time <=1 in this example).

The downside of doing this is that it uses more memory than a simple loop.

An example of this would be:

```
def funcName(time):
    sum = 0
    if (time > 1):
        sum = funcName(time-1)
        sum += 5000**(time-1)
    return sum
```